# How do i use resolve object in Angular Js to access and load the specific object before the route can be displayed to user in MVC Web Api?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i want to access to list of employees via resolve object in angular js before the route can be displayed to user in MVC Web Api.

in app.js file

```
 when('/', {
              templateUrl: '/x.html',
              controller: 'XCtrl'

          }).
```

what do i write in servis.js and controller.js file and how to get employees from web api controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolve object tells AngularJS that each of these resolve keys needs to be satisfied
before the route can be displayed to the user. For example, we want to load all the employees, or
an individual employee, and make sure we have the server response before we display the
page. So we tell the route provider that we have employees(or a employee), and then tell it how
to fetch it.

in app.js file

```
when('/', {
              templateUrl: '/x.html',
              controller: 'XCtrl',
              resolve: {
                  employees: function (EmployeeLoader) {
                      return EmployeeLoader();
                  }
              },
          }).
```

in xControllers.js file

```
xControllers.controller('XCtrl', ['$scope', 'employees',
function ($scope,employees) {
 $scope.employees = employees;
}
]);
```

in Service.js file

```
xServices.factory('Employees', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Employee/GetEmployees');
}]);

xServices.factory('EmployeeLoader', ['Employees', '$q', function (Employees, $q) {
    return function () {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        Employees.query(function (result) {
            delay.resolve(result);
        },
        function () {
            delay.reject('Unable to fetch timesheets');
        });
        return delay.promise;
    }
}]);
```

The EmployeeLoader service use  from Employees service to request to server with GetEmployees method and this method fetch employees and return it.

in web api (server side) controller that it can be class:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public List<EmployeeViewModel> GetEmployees()
        {                            
                //fetch the employees
                return employees;

        }
```